# Why dovecot use "postfix_accounts.users" to retrieve mail user information after username/password auth?

Tags: postfix, configuration, dovecot, debugging, authorization

I had set up a mail server in my Rocky Linux 9.1 that comes with postfix, dovecot and mysql (refer to https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-setup-mail-server-on-centos/).

Every thing is updated. (postfix-3.5.9,dovecot-2.3.16 and mariadb-10.5.22).

I had set mysql database properly and there are three tables (accounts_table,alias_table,domains_table) under database (named as: postfix_accounts)

I had set up "mail_home = /var/vmail/%d/%n" in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf and I tested it by run [doveconf | grep mail].

After I restarted postfix and dovecot service. seems they all works fine.

When I tried to connect from mail client by using username/password. I got authen failed error. When I check dovecot log by run [journalctl -u dovecot -f]. I found

```
.......
auth-worker(1696): Debug: conn unix:auth-worker (pid=1695,uid=97): auth-worker<1>: sql(xxxx@xxxxx.com.au,10.0.1.235,<3PNSoagMPfkKAAHr>): Performing passdb lookup
.......
auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK        1        user=xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com.au        User=xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com.au
.......
auth: Debug: sql(xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com.au,10.0.1.235,<3PNSoagMPfkKAAHr>): Performing userdb lookup
auth-worker(1696): Debug: mysql(127.0.0.1): Finished query 'SELECT home, uid, gid FROM users WHERE username = 'xxxxx' AND domain = 'xxxxxxx.com.au'' in 0 msecs: Table 'postfix_accounts.users' doesn't exist
auth-worker(1696): Warning: sqlpool(mysql): Query failed, retrying: Table 'postfix_accounts.users' doesn't exist
.........
auth: Debug: master userdb out: FAIL        2733244417
```

From above debug information we can see, the "auth-worker" is trying to fetch the user's id, group id and home information from database, that not exist (sure not, we don't create it).

I tried to find out how to configure dovecot "auth-worker" not use the mysql database to look up userdb information, but I don't find any thing here.

Does any one have the same situation and how to fix it. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had find out the solution:

find out file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf.ext

comment out:

```
#userdb {
#  driver = sql
#  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
#}
```

and uncomment

```
userdb {
  driver = static
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
}
```

run [sudo systemctl restart dovecot]